# Sending Packets with Java ServerSocket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

Hey i'm creating a multiplayer themed game in java.
I have multi-threaded the server-inputs and now i'm doing the server sending stuff.

I'm using the ObjectOutputStream to send objects and i'm looping thrugh a List of connected Clients. 
My question is now: if i need to thread those sendings or can i keep my system of looping thrugh the list of client and just use the write() method or does this method has a callback, so slower internet connections or send issues stuck or slower the loop?

```
public void sendPacketToAllClients(JSONObject object) {
    for(Client c:clients) {
        c.sendPacket(object);
    }
}
```

and the send method of the client contains:

```
 oOs.writeObject(object);
```

Comment: You have to answer these questions yourselves. If your game is real-time(words with friends), you definitely don't want a lag between players. You cannot loop through the clients. Better to have listener threads in pub-sub model.

Comment: Looping does not cause lag, unless the loop size is very large.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about polling versus thread per connection. Both are legitimate approaches. The thread per connection approach takes more effort to implement, but it will scale better if your network connections are slow. However, that's not likely as you start out. You can always refactor later.